# Error while reading other process memory

Tags: windows, api, memory

I'm using ReadProcessMemory to read a single byte out of a process i've created.
Since i'm attaching as a debugger, i'm reading addresses that are being executed now (or in the near past).

but i get a 299 error for ReadProcessMemory via GetLastError() on some addresses only (some works fine..)

On the cases i get an error, i call VirtualQueryEx, and the memInfo protect is 0x1, while the type & baseAddress are 0x0 (but the region size is some normal number), also VirtualQueryEx isn't failing..

if i call VirtualProtectEx for those cases, i get error 487 (Attempt to access invalid address).

i thought maybe the address i'm trying to read is paged out, thus all the errors, but it doesn't seem right since, as i've already mentioned, its an address that was executed recently.

ideas anyone?

Comment: Sounds like you've got the wrong address, how did you determine it?  What is the value of `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION->State` ?

Comment: Unless you suspend all threads in the target process, allocated memory is a moving target, and trying to access it requires luck. I don't know why you think that paged-out memory wouldn't be accessible through `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: I attached a debugger, and on every single step exception i read the memory address that i got from the exception. the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION->State is 0x00010000.
also, the threads are suspended since i'm handling a debug exception..

Comment: 0x10000 means the address isn't allocated.  If the process being debugged has stepped into unallocated memory, that means it crashed.

Comment: But it didn't crash :( so i don't know why it isn't allocated (allegedly). and when i don't get this error, everything works fine and as expected...

Comment: It is very unlikely that Windows is lying to you about this.  You will need to double-check your code to make sure it is doing what you think it is.  For example, are you sure you're looking at a single-step exception and not an access violation exception?  And that your debugging code handles an access violation exception properly?  (It would be a good idea to make the child deliberately generate an access violation, to verify that your debugging code handles it properly.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through all the memory, calling VirtualQueryEx() to make sure the memory is valid before calling ReadProcessMemory()

You need to make sure that MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.State is MEM_COMMIT in most cases.

This whole operation can be easy to screw up, because you didn't supply any code I will provide a working solution that should work in 95% of situations.  It's ok for bytesRead to be different than regionSize, you just need to handle that situation correctly.  You don't need to take permissions in most cases using VirtualProtect because all valid memory **should** have read access.

```cpp
int main()
{
    DWORD procid = GetProcId("notepad.exe");

    unsigned char* addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procid);

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            char* buffer = new char[mbi.RegionSize]{ 0 };
            SIZE_T bytesRead = 0;

            if (ReadProcessMemory(hProc, addr, buffer, mbi.RegionSize, &bytesRead))
            {
                if (bytesRead)
                {
                    //scan from buffer[0] to buffer[bytesRead]
                }
                else
                {
                    //scan from buffer[0] to buffer[mbi.RegionSize]
                }
            }

            delete[] buffer;
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

Reminder: This is just a PoC to teach you the concept.